# Fixed size div which sits to the right of a main div that fills up remainder of screen

Tags: css, layout, html

I have seen lots of questions but none that seem to quite solve my problem.

I have two divs: mainbody and rightpanel. I would like the rightpanel to be a fixed size (210px), and to sit to the right of the mainbody div which fills up all the remaining space of the window.

So it would resize like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|                             |          |
|                             |          |
|                             |          |
|       mainbody              |rightpanel|
|                             |          |
|                             |          |
|                             |          |
+----------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|  mainbody          |rightpanel|
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
+-------------------------------+
```

My current solution below sort of works, but if the window is resized to below about 900px the right bar gets pushed to the bottom as the 25% remaining space gets too small for it to fit into, so I force the window to horizontally scroll at this width.

```
#wrap {
    width:97%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#mainbody {
    float:left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#rightpanel  {
    float:right;
    width: 22%;
    min-width: 210px;
    max-width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-22-fluid-fixed/

Comment: @sunn0 This is exactly what I was looking for, and it seems like it should work, but the rightpanel is still being pushed to below the mainbody, and so the -210px bit is actually pushing the off the screen to the left when I use this layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the right panel before the main content if you float it:

```
<div id="rightpanel">blah blah blah</div>
<div id="mainbody">blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #rightpanel {
        width:210px;
        float:right;
        background-color:red;
    }
    #mainbody {
       margin-right:210px;
       background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

This will keep the right-hand panel aligned properly even if the page is resized.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" style="background: #ff00ff; ">
        Left
        <div id="right" style="width: 210px; float: right; background: #ff0000;">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one makes the left fill the entire width of the window and the right is pushed down to below the left on, sitting on the right hand side of the window but starting right at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 0):

```
#mainbody {
float: left;
}
#rightpanel {
width: 210px;
}
```

Have you tried something like this?

Comment: This makes the mainbody fill the entire width of the page and the right panel goes on the left hand side of the page, behind the main body, though it is stretched so that the content is pushed to below where the mainbody finishes.

Answer (score 0):

look on my site : http://www.mcohenlawyer.com/
is it what you want ?

if yes, this is the CSS code :
(supported in all major browsers)

```
div.menubar {
    position: fixed; /*can be absolute too*/
    width: 158px;
    /*what comes latter is not relevant for your question*/
    /*......*/
}
.body { /*the main body*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 180px;/*can be 159px, if you don't want space between divs*/
    min-height: 870px;
    /*what comes latter is not relevant for your question*/
    /*......*/
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but your CSS is making the right panel just sit on the left hand side of the screen over the top of the main body. I'm starting to feel there must be something else in my page which is messing it up, because none of these solutions are working, and I think they should be!